# Active Storage with Single Table Inheritance and different attachables (STI) #43780

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, rails-activestorage

I'm using ActiveStorage in a solution I'm building to create documents with a block builder like interface, but I'm running into the N+1 query problem when using STI in combination with active storage and different attachment names.

Given a ContentBlock which is polymorphic to a contentable

```
class ContentBlock < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :contentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

A document which has_many of these different kind of ContentBlock.

```
class Document
  has_many :content_blocks, -> { order(position: :asc) }, as: :contentable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

A subset of content blocks as an example: ImageBlock, ProductBlock each with one or many different names for an attached file.

```
class ImageBlock < ContentBlock
 has_one_attached :image
end

class ProductBlock < ContentBlock
 has_one_attached :product_image
end
```

Querying this Document and all it's associated ContentBlock records is easy by providing includes(:content_blocks).

The problem starts when needing information about the ActiveStorage::Attachment records included inside of every subset of ContentBlock

**with_attached_image** works on ImageBlock but not on ProductBlock

**with_attached_product_image** works on ProductBlock but not on ImageBlock

I can't seem to figure out a way to load all of the associated ActiveStorage::Attachment & ActiveStorage::Blob records without bumping into the N+1 query.

Am I tackling this problem the wrong way? Are there other ways?

**Solution:**

As discussed before it was impossible to solve the N+1 query on a type of content block based relationship.

The easiest and most performant solution I found was to declare all my possible relations a derived `Contentblock` could have on the `ContentBlock` class itself.

I then declared the optimised default scopes on each individual block.

```
class ContentBlock
  # Relations are defined here to make proper use of includes(:relation)

  # ContentBlock::Image
  has_one_attached :image

  # ContentBlock::Sign
  has_many :signatures, as: :signable, dependent: :destroy

  DEFAULT_SCOPE = [
    image_attachment: :blob,
    signatures: Signature::DEFAULT_SCOPE
  ].freeze

  default_scope do
    includes(DEFAULT_SCOPE)
  end
end
```

The downside of this is that you might overfetch data in some cases. A `TextBlock` will also do a join to `active_storage_attachments` even if it doesn't have an image attached.

The upside is that the N+1 query is gone for good with the tradeoff of having some records overfetch which in my use case is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to move `has_one_attached` up to `ContentBlock`

```rb
class ContentBlock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contentable, polymorphic: true
  has_one_attached :media

  class << self
    def media_alias(name)
      alias_method name, :media
      alias_method "#{name}=".to_sym, :media=
    end
  end
end

class ImageBlock < ContentBlock
  media_alias :image
end

class ProductBlock < ContentBlock
  media_alias :product_image
end
```

now you could use **with_attached_media** to preload attachments, and still could access `ImageBlock#image`, `ProductBlock#product_image` as before.

Comment: This was partially what I was looking for! Thanks for the help! I've written my solution up top.